# ORTOOLS CP SAT - XOR and AND combined

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I am still learning ORTOOLS CP-SAT which is a great tool!
I am getting into boolean operations difficulties.
For instance in Python, I have an array of an array of expressions (I mean BoundedLinearExpression) organized like this:

```
    my_list = [ [ a<5, b>3, c>5 ],
                [ d>8, e<=3, f+a=10 ],
                 ...
              ]
```

I want to make a logical AND on each line... and then a XOR on all the results I got. I have no clue how to do that.
Does someone know the answer?
Thanks for your help

```
     # it should end this way:
     model.AddBoolXOr(???)
```

Comment: Also note that `XOr` is not the same as `sum(...) == 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading [This doc section](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/channeling.md)

You need to create Boolean variables for all bounded linear expressions.

Comment: Hi, could you update this link (gets 404).  TIA.

Comment: Done. Thanks for flagging that.